# Dart Stream: How to merge emitted items, when they're short after eachother?

Tags: dart, stream

Let's assume I have a `Stream<int>` emitting integers in different time deltas i.e. between 5ms and 1000ms.

When the delta is <= 50ms I want to merge them. for example:

`3, (delta:100) 5, (delta:27) 6, (delta:976) 3`

I want to consume: 3, 11(merged using addition), 3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [debounceBuffer](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/debounceBuffer.html) stream transformer from the [stream_transform](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform) package.

```
stream
  .transform(debounceBuffer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50)))
  .map((list) => list.fold(0, (t, e) => t + e))
```

Comment: thanks for the tip with stream_transform. Coming from kotlin/android/rxjava2, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can write that easily enough yourself:

```
Stream<int> debounce(
    Stream<int> source, Duration limit, int combine(int a, int b)) async* {
  int prev;
  var stopwatch;
  await for (var event in source) {
    if (stopwatch == null) {
      // First event.
      prev = event;
      stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
    } else {
      if (stopwatch.elapsed < limit) {
        prev = combine(prev, event);
      } else {
        yield prev;
        prev = event;
      }
      stopwatch.reset();
    }
  }
  // If any event, yield prev.
  if (stopwatch != null) yield prev;
}
```